# Using the return value from scanf in the C programming language as a check

Tags: c, validation, input

How do you use the return value from scanf to make sure it is a double I've got?

```
double input;

do {  /* do this as long as it not a double */
  printf("Input?");
  scanf("%lf", &input);
} while(scanf("%lf", &input) != 1); /* this will not work */
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`scanf` will return the number of items assigned. In your case, since the format string contains only `%lf`, it will return `1` exactly in the case where you got your `double`. The problem with your code is that you first call `scanf` inside the loop, which will read the `double` off the stream. Then, in your `while` condition, you call `scanf` again, but there isn't another `double` to be read, so `scanf` does not do anything.

The way I would write your code would be something like

```
int no_assigned;
do {
    printf("Input?");
    no_assigned = scanf("%lf", &input);
} while (no_assigned != 1);
```

The extra variable is there because it feels to me like the `scanf` is code that should be inside the loop, not in the `while` condition, but that is really a personal preference; you can eliminate the extra variable and move (note, move, not copy) the `scanf` call inside the condition instead.

EDIT: And here's the version using `fgets` that's probably better:

```
double input;
char buffer[80];

do {
    printf("Input? ");
    fflush(stdout); // Make sure prompt is shown
    if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL)
        break; // Got EOF; TODO: need to recognize this after loop
    // TODO: If input did not fit into buffer, discard until newline
} while (sscanf(buffer, "%lf", &input) != 1);
```

Comment: +1 for saying it's personal preference. I prefer it inside the loop myself, but who am I to judge?

Comment: I did this but I have to fflush(stdin); after scanf or it will loop forever ( if I put it in the whilecondition)?

Comment: No, don't do `fflush(stdin);` as that is not guaranteed to do what you think it does. The `scanf` will indeed leave a newline in the input. If you use `scanf` in the future, that should not matter as `scanf` skips whitespace, but if you use some other input function, you will need to get rid of the newline before that. In fact, a better approach would probably be to input a line in the `while` loop with `fgets` and then use `sscanf` on that line in the same way as you now use `scanf`.

Comment: Ok, great answer BTW! 
But if you read something in and leave stuff "behind" does that mean you have made a poor job reading?
And I understand you have an alternative thing going in there but I don't really comprehend this.
Is there a safe method that swallows everything including the \n?

Comment: The "safer" method is what I edited in afterwards of using `fgets` as `fgets` reads complete lines so you won't leave extra newlines into the buffer. `scanf` is not really well-suited for interactive input; the comp.lang.c FAQ has a few things to say about it: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Answer (score 2):

scanf() and friends return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned. No information related to type. But since you've specified `lf` in the conversion string, you'll get a double - I think I'm missing your point though.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Michael said, scanf() returns and integer that represents the number of elements suceccesfully read. As far as I can see from the manpage you can't use the return value to verify if what was read is a double or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
double input;

do {  /* do this as long as it not a double */
  printf("Input?");
} while(!scanf("%lf", &input));
```

Answer (score 0):

scanf() will return the number of input given / provided. It will not return any data-type related result.